# No bandpass filters with coax terminals?

Tags: connector

I want to try out an airband bandpass filter, but it seems like all the filters for sale use SMA connectors but the antenna is, of course, N type connector. So, this seems kind of crazy to me. If virtually all antennas use N type connectors, why would the filters use SMA connectors?

Comment: SMA connectors are used with coax all the time.  Depends on the type/size of coax, of course.

Comment: SMA connectors *are* coax connectors, so I'm not sure what you're talking about here. Are you referring to some specific connector (perhaps the F connector common in the US, or the Belling-Lee connector common in Europe, or the BNC connector common in CCTV systems worldwide) thinking it's just called "coax"?

Comment: @Hearth Ok maybe I misunderstand what coax means. My antenna has an N connector which I don't think is the same thing as SMA.

Comment: A coax connector is any connector that has an inner contact that is completely (or mostly, in some cases) surrounded by an outer shield contact. Common coaxial connectors are SMA, BNC, TNC, N, F, Belling-Lee, SMA, SMB, SSMA, MMCX, U.FL, 9/16 DIN, UHF, 2.92mm, 7mm/AMC7, SHV, MHV, and literally hundreds more. All are intended to be used with coaxial cable, and all have specific characteristic impedances (except for really bad ones like the UHF connector which was made in like the 30s or something) so they don't interfere with high-frequency signals.

Comment: 1) Include a link to an example of such a filter. 2) An SMA connector is designed for use with **COAX**ial cables, often RG316. This cable and SMA connectors are for a characteristic impedance of **50 Ohms**. *which I don't think is the same thing as SMA.* No they're very different. N-type is much larger and for thicker COAX cables than SMA. Even all SMA are not the same, there are SMA connectors cables for extremely high frequencies ( > 20 GHz) that are not to be used with "standard SMA" connectors. If you stay under 1 GHz, there's no issue though.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The ones for very high frequencies are properly called "2.92mm connectors" or "3.5mm connectors"; they're all intermateable with SMA, but are not strictly speaking SMA connectors.

Comment: You can get type N to sma adapters on amazon for cheap. Airband is VHF and not very demanding for typical power levels of a few Watts on down.

Comment: Either buy an adapter or just cut off the N connector and crimp a more common coax connector like SMA or BNC.

Answer (score 0):

> My antenna has an N connector

If so, that antenna is probably the wrong frequency for your application. Regardless, to adapt between SMA and N, you need an adapter. For example: [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-sv-microwave/SF1104-6007/6201673).

> WOAH!

... you say when you see the price: $138.80

Well, then, just buy the correct antenna, one with an SMA connector already in place.

Comment: If the OP does not need the full 18 GHz bandwidth, a lower priced adapter can readily be found. OP is using airband which is VHF.

Comment: Let's not scare them; you can get SMA to N adapters [for like $15](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-rf/242113/1012018). Rated up to 11 GHz, too; way more than enough for most applications.